# Radio button and label enclosing <xmp> tag to display in same line (only using HTML)

Tags: html

I want my radio buttons and label to be in same horizontal line. I'm using xmp tag to display raw html as options with radio button. But the text in xmp starts in new line. Is there any alternative to xmp tag.

```
       `<input class="answer" type="radio" name="q3" value="0">
        <label><xmp>The <head> section</xmp></label>
        <br></br>
        <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q3" value="1">
        <label><xmp>Both <head> section and the body section are 
        correct</xmp></label>
        <br></br>
        <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q3" value="0">
        <label><xmp>The <body> section</xmp></label>
        <br></br>
        <input class="answer" type="radio" name="q3" value="0">
        <label>None of these</label>`
```

[Here's how the gui looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDupv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware:

> The <xmp> element was used to surround HTML example text that should be rendered without interpreting any HTML elements between the opening and closing <xmp> tags. **The element was deprecated in HTML 3.2 and is now obsolete.** <xmp> was designed to render content exactly as typed, without compressing spaces.

Instead you should use `&lt;` for the lesser than tag, and `&gt;` for the grearter than tag, if you require the labels to contain non-functional HTML tags:

```
<input class="answer" type="radio" name="q3" value="0">
<label>The &lt;head&gt; section is here</label>
<br />
<input class="answer" type="radio" name="q3" value="1">
<label>2nd section goes here</label>
<br />
```

Which gives:

[image: output]

Please also note that the `<br></br>` can be shorthanded as: `<br />` although these aren't really suitable for laying out elements on a page, although I think that's beyond the scope of this question.

A full list of available characters can be found [here](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Comment: Thanks!!. It's working. I was using <xmp> tag even with methods and brackets. Now   I figured out it was unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably worth looking at Bootstrap's [Form documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/).

Enabling Bootstrap is as simple as putting this in the `head` section of your document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-azvvU9xKluwHFJ0Cpgtf0CYzK7zgtOznnzxV4924X1w=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Then you can just play with the examples in the docs.

For example, here's a login form rendered nicely: https://jsfiddle.net/h4sdpqtg/

Comment: Is there any other way without using bootstrap?. This is part of my school project and I am only able to use html. Maybe an alternative to xmp tag??

Comment: @harpreet ok friend, I added another answer ;-)